# Is Java showing ISO 639-2 languages incorrectly in case of Finnish?

Tags: java, locale

Why Java is showing ISO 639-2 language codes incorrectly in case of Finnish language? With ISO 639 codes it gives the correct language name in Finnish.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale fi = new Locale("fi");
    Locale fin = new Locale("fin");
    Locale en = new Locale("en", "EN");
    Locale sv = new Locale("sv");

    System.out.println("fi: " +fi.getDisplayLanguage(fi));
    System.out.println("fin: " +fin.getDisplayLanguage(fi));
    System.out.println("sv: " +fin.getDisplayLanguage(sv));
    System.out.println("en: " +fin.getDisplayLanguage(en));


}

fi: suomi
fin: Finnish***?? Why this is in English, not in Finnish?
sv: Finska
en: Finnish
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `"fin"` is not a valid value for the language argument of the `Locale(String)` constructor.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), the language argument should be (emphasis mine):

> ISO 639 alpha-2 or alpha-3 language code, or registered language subtags up to 8 alpha letters (for future enhancements). ***When a language has both an alpha-2 code and an alpha-3 code, the alpha-2 code must be used***. You can find a full list of valid language codes in the IANA Language Subtag Registry (search for "Type: language"). The language field is case insensitive, but Locale always canonicalizes to lower case.

Because Finnish has an alpha-2 code (`"fi"`), this is what you should use, and not `"fin"`. Otherwise you are effectively creating a Locale object for some sort of default Locale (English?).

Comment: Weird that it shows correctly in Swedish though. Then again, `Locale` has plenty of problems.

Comment: Not sure about that. I tested it myself and it shows:`fi: suomi,
fin: fin,
sv: fin,
en: fin`, which makes sense to me. Perhaps the code snippet posted by the OP does not exactly correspond to the output shown in the question?

Comment: I get the same output as OP. Disclaimer: I'm Finnish.

Comment: Uhm, then I am not sure what is going on internally, but in any case the Javadocs clearly state that an alpha-2 code should be used if both alpha-2 and alpha-3 codes exist.

Comment: Well, I assume we have different locale information in our Java installations. But your answer still stands, especially in light of this additional discrepancy.

Comment: But fin is ISO 639-2 code, not fi. Fi is ISO 639-1.

Comment: @MarFoo That is exactly the issue. The Javadocs say that if there is an alpha-2 code (ISO 639-1) and an alpha-3 code (ISO 639-2), then the alpha-2 code must be used.

Comment: @Grodriguez So ISO 639 alpha-2 means iso639-1? OK, so then the documentation is correct, still I wonder that why Swedish and English is working, but not Finnish in case three letters codes. fin.getDisplayLanguage(fi)) is not working, but fin.getDisplayLanguage(sv) is.

Comment: @MarFoo Yes -- the name is a bit misleading but iso639-1 is the one that actually defines the alpha-2 space (see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639)